# Set "min-width" or "max-width" in a media query passing a parameter to a mixin

Tags: less, mixins, less-mixins

I would like to make dynamic MIN/MAX suffix in properties defined in a Less MediaQuery.

I wrote this code but it does not compile:

```
@screen-md: 800px;

.MEDIAQUERY(@min-max, @size) 
{
  @media screen and (@{min-max}-width: @size) 
  { 
    @{min-max}-width:100px;
  }
}

header 
{
  background-color: blue;

  .MEDIAQUERY ( @min-max: max, @size: @screen-md );
}
```

While `@{min-max}-width:100px;` is a correct syntax, equivalent applied in Mediaquery definition is not allowed, but I need to set sometime "max-width" value, and others "min-width" value in my media queries. How to obtain this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option 1: (Using a variable and interpolation)**

You can do it like below

```
.MEDIAQUERY(@min-max, @size) {
      @mediaQuery: ~"screen and (@{min-max}-width: @{size})";
      @media @mediaQuery {
            @{min-max}-width:100px;
      }
}
```

---

**Option 2: (Using Guards)**

You can use guards in the mixin like below to check what was the value that was passed for the `@min-max` parameter and then output the appropriate CSS based on it.

```
.MEDIAQUERY(@min-max, @size){
    & when (@min-max = min) {
        @media screen and (min-width: @size) {
            min-width:100px;
        }
    }
    & when (@min-max = max) {
        @media screen and (max-width: @size) {
            max-width:100px;
        }
    }
}
```

---

When the above mixin is called like below (with either of the options mentioned above):

```
header 
{
  background-color: blue;
  .MEDIAQUERY ( @min-max: max, @size: @screen-md );
}

div{
  background-color: red;
  .MEDIAQUERY ( @min-max: min, @size: @screen-md );
}
```

it would compile into the below CSS:

```
header {
    background-color: blue;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    header {
        max-width: 100px;
    }
}
div {
    background-color: red;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 800px) {
    div {
        min-width: 100px;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, could be a solution, but I thought that could be possible to get the same result in more compact way using mechanism like `@{...}` or ~"...", etc... so one of "syntax workaround" that often solve problems like this... I hope that LESS team could make possible my original syntax sooner or later, is clearly more compact and much intuitive.

Comment: I don't think that is possible mate. But maybe leave the question open and see if any better answer comes your way. I will also try and see.

Comment: @LucaDetomi: I stand corrected mate. It is perfectly possible to achieve it in a more compact way. Please refer to Option 1 in my answer.

Comment: GREAT!!!!! just one thing, I thought that use of `~` results in a "string printed as is" and that `@{min-max}-width` will not be interpreted.... Can you explain me why this correctly run? Thank you.

Comment: Yes, generally it prints the string as is, but when we use the `@{var}` syntax, it prints the corresponding variable's value.